# Type safety when handling public and internal interfaces on same implementation

Tags: c#, interface, soa

The title might be a little bit off, so let me explain the situation.

I am in SOA (service layer in one assembly, no microservices) and I have a service A. It inherits from a public interface which exposes its "public" functionality:

```
public interface IServiceA
{
   IServiceB ServiceB { get; set; }

   BusinesObjectDto Find(long id);
   ...
}
```

To an user from outside of the service layer this is what they should see. I also have an internal interface IInternalServiceA (still have not decided on the best name for this):

```
internal interface InternalServiceA
   : IServiceA
{
   BusinessObject InternalFind(long id, bool checkCacheFirst = false)
}
```

To the outside of service layer, the communication is based on dtos, but within the service layer, the services (or any other components), should expose their domain objects/business objects/models between themselves. Also, when services talk to each other inside the service layer, there might be methods which include more specific flags (checkCacheFirst for example) which is not proper to expose to outsiders.

The dependencies of services are publicly exposed on the interface, and can be hooked up outside of service layer (if not, they are lazily initialized inside the service). For example:

```
var serviceA = new ServiceA();
serviceA.ServiceB = new ServiceB();
```

The question is, in the ServiceA implementation, how can I handle getting the  internal service interface from the public service interface? Obviously I can cast, but I am looking to architect this so I can have type safety.

Comment: Why not just have two interface definitions, one for external and one for internal?

Comment: Thats where I was going. I had a public one and an internal (explicitly implemented) one. The problem is that I cannot make the internal inherit from the public. This will cause me to hard cast all over the place (from public to internal), because my services expose dependent services using the public interface and these dependent services can be initialized about the service layer. For example, the controller can create service A,B,C, where A is dependent on B and C, and the controller assignes A.B = new B(), and A.C = new C(). I hope this is understandable.

Comment: I actually went another route and dont think I am going to continue to try to do this. It seems too complicated. I also tried with C# extension methods to expose the methods on the internal interface, but it is still too complicated.